# When does the Cowboy Bebop Manga take place within the Anime?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I know that the Cowboy Bebop manga was written and produced by someone other than Shinichiro Watanabe (although the English credits say: *Cooperation: Shinichiro Watanabe / Sunrise*); the manga **Cowboy Bebop**, shortly after the TV series ended, and that for all intents and purposes, they are the same canon as the TV series and movie; and the manga **Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star**, which was written alongside the original TV series airing. The chapters themselves are pretty similar to an episode of the TV series, so are there specific time frames, or episodes that these chapters are reported to take place? Or is it ambiguous and can safely sit somewhere in the middle of the series (after all the cast have been introduced and are together, before the cast start separating)? Is *"Shooting Star"* on a completely different timeline?

Comment: Which manga is it? *Cowboy Bebop* or *Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star*?

Comment: @JNat Sorry, should have clarified, *not* the Shooting Star manga which was written alongside the TV series airing.

Comment: Should I edit my answer then to exclude *Shooting Star*? Or leave it like that and you change your question to fit them both (so it would better concentrate the information, while also preventing a second one from popping up)?

Comment: @JNat I'll edit my question to include both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually two mangas for Cowboy Bebop:

- **Cowboy Bebop: Shooting Star**
  This one is supposed to be an alternative telling of the anime series' story. This one has elements of the story as told in the anime and some entirely new elements.
  Being 'a new take' on the anime, I guess this one is supposed to replace its timeline.
  *[Source 1](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=2897) and [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cowboy_Bebop_chapters#Cowboy_Bebop:_Shooting_Star)*
- **Cowboy Bebop**
  This one features side-stories, which are supposed to be separate from the anime story.
  According to *Anime News Network*, this one is supposed to take place before the ending of the series (but they do not cite any references). It could fit [somewhat like the movie does](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/208/cowboy-bebop-connection-between-anime-and-movie).
  *[Source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=1555)*